# ActiveMQ SSL performance

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, activemq-classic

I have ActiveMQ performance issues when using the SslBrokerService.

I am sending 250 KB from server1 to server2 and 1 Byte back from server2 to server1 while server2 is the broker:

```
Server1 -> 250 KB to Queue1, Server2 listing on Queue1
Server2 -> 1 Byte to Queue2, Server1 listing on Queue2
```

When I am not using SSL i was able to repeat the above action  ~ **115** times per second.

When using SSL i get ~**38** times per second.

Comments:

1. I am using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 as the cipher suite.
2. I am not counting the handshake process in my calculation and I am using the same session (I am doing handshake only once)
3. Using pure Java socket give me better numbers : 260 without SSL and 97 with SSL
4. I am using ssl+nio

Comment: What version of the broker?

Comment: That version is very old, try a new one (5.14.0), there's been tons of fixes and improvements since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Java's poor GCM performance, Once i switched to a better GCM implementation i got the desired benchmark.